# cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'LPCWSTR'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, char, bmp

Im trying to load a BMP file

```
AUX_RGBImageRec *LoadBMP(char *Filename)  // Loads A Bitmap Image
{
    FILE *File=NULL;                      // File Handle

    if (!Filename)                        // Make Sure A Filename Was Given
    {
        return NULL;                      // If Not Return NULL
    }

    File=fopen(Filename,"r");             // Check To See If The File Exists

    if (File)                             // Does The File Exist?
    {
        fclose(File);                     // Close The Handle
        return auxDIBImageLoad(Filename); // Load The Bitmap And Return A Pointer
    }

    return NULL;                          // If Load Failed Return NULL
}
```

this has come from an example however i'm now getting the error

> error C2664: 'auxDIBImageLoadW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'LPCWSTR'

how could I correct this?

Answer (score 33):

You're compiling your application with Character-Set set to UNICODE (Project Settings -> Configuration Options -> General). Windows header files use #defines to "map" function names to either nameA (for multi-byte strings) or nameW (for unicode strings).

That means somewhere in a header file there will be a #define like this

```
#define auxDIBImageLoad auxDIBImageLoadW
```

So you're not actually calling `auxDIBImageLoad` (there is no function with that name), you're calling `auxDIBImageLoadW`. And `auxDIBImageLoadW` expects a unicode string (`wchar_t const*`). You're passing a multi-byte string (`char const*`).

You can do one of the following

- change your project to use multi-byte character set (-> project settings)
- explicitly call the multi-byte version of the function by replacing `auxDIBImageLoad` with `auxDIBImageLoadA`
- change your `LoadBMP` function  to accept a unicode string itself
- convert the string to unicode inside `LoadBMP`

I'd recommend either changing `LoadBMP` to accept a unicode string itself or calling `auxDIBImageLoadA` directly (in that order).
Changing the project settings might be OK if it doesn't break a lot of other code.
I would *not* suggest converting the string though, since it's unnecessary. Calling `auxDIBImageLoadA` directly is far easier, and the result is the same.

Answer (score 10):

You have a few options:

- Change the 'character set' option in your project settings from 'Unicode' to 'Not Set'
- Call `auxDIBImageLoadA` instead of `auxDIBImageLoad`
- Change `Filename`'s type from `char*` to `wchar_t*`
- Use [`std::mbstowcs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) to convert Filename from a `char*` to a `wchar_t*`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your trying to use two different character sets.  'char *' is the typical ANSI and LPCWSTR is the wide character (i.e. unicode).  If you would like to use char* change the 'Character Set' property in your project setting to 'No Set'.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **MultiByteToWideChar()** the following way:

```
void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 ...
 wchar_t filename[4096] = {0};
 MultiByteToWideChar(0, 0, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]), filename, strlen(argv[1]));

 // RenderFile() requires LPCWSTR (or wchar_t*, respectively)
 hr = pGraph->RenderFile(filename, NULL);
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the character array to a LPCWSTR.  You can see this in the 2nd guys post [here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?threadid=360665)