# Select "Use Unicode Character Set" in Gnu Makefile

Tags: unicode, makefile

I have a long-standing application that I'm normally able to compile equally well from Visual Studio or from a makefile using Gnu Make (but still using the Microsoft C++ compiler).

Recently I modified it by incorporating a third-party library. On trying to compile it for the first time from within Visual Studio, I obtained the common ["C2664: ...cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480588/cannot-convert-parameter-1-from-char-to-lpcwstr) error, which I resolved by going to the 'General' tab in the Project Properties dialog and selecting the "Use Unicode Character Set" option.

I'd now like to compile the application from my makefile, but naturally I get the same error. Is there a compiler switch that I can use to have an equivalent effect to "Use Unicode Character Set", or any other way of effecting this from within the makefile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a dedicated compiler switch.  Unicode is selected based on preprocessor macros.  IIRC, `UNICODE` for MFC and `_UNICODE` for the MSVCRT.  Use `/D UNICODE /D _UNICODE`.