# Setting Character set for MSVC compiler from another IDE (Qt Creator)

Tags: qt, visual-c++, character-encoding, qt-creator, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to compile legacy code in Qt Creator using the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 10.0 (x86), and I am getting the classic error:

> cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'LPCWSTR'

Rather than edit the code (something I should not be doing, it is a 3rd party SDK), the solution is to go into Visual Studio general settings and change the character set to

> 'Use Multi-byte character set'

(as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480588/cannot-convert-parameter-1-from-char-to-lpcwstr))

However, I'm not using the Visual Studio IDE and don't have that setting. So I need to know what setting that actually does in terms of code/compilation. Does it set a compiler flag or #define something? How can I achieve the same in Qt Creator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick check in Visual Studio and this is what I found:

If the option is **Use Unicode Character Set**, you'll have these two compiler options:

```
/D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE"
```

However, if it's **Use Multi-Byte Character Set**, you'll have:

```
/D "_MBCS"
```

So you either need to update the command line and change from `/D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE"` to `/D "_MBCS"` or #define somewhere an `_MBCS` symbol.

Comment: Cool thanks, this page here corroborates with what you're saying
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey142t48(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: It seems Qt automatically defined UNICODE for you, and there's no way to undefine it from your project. You can add /D "_MBCS" to the QMAKE_CXXFLAGS qmake variable, but /D "UNICODE" and /D "_MBCS" end up getting passed as arguments to cl.
To make Multi-Byte Character Set the default in Qt Creator, you have to edit the qmake.conf file for your MSVC settings, mine is at:
C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010
On the defines line you need to remove UNICODE and add _MBCS. Not a great workaround but Qt Creator doesn't give you a UI option to change that like Visual Studio does.

Comment: @oggmonster. I was able to remove the UNICODE define and add _MBCS by adding the following to my .pro file.
DEFINES -= UNICODE
DEFINES += _MBCS

Answer (score 1):

it must have some MFC function calling in your code, which use "LPTSTR" etc,
the old .h files, may include: StdAfx.h,  just edit it:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER

#define assert ASSERT
#define snprintf _snprintf

//remove UNICODE define
#ifdef UNICODE
#undef UNICODE
#endif

#include <afxwin.h>

#endif
```

then it will go through without Unicode define,
no need to modify \msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010\qmake.conf

Comment: in .pro file,  add DEFINES *= _AFXDLL _MBCS